# Best practice: sending a stored procedure for "SQL Command from Variable" in OLE DB Source?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

In a SSIS ETL, I have a query that I need to run on a server/db that does not allow us to create stored procedures.

I would normally use the stored procedure in my variable as the source for my OLE DB source:

[image: Usual method]

However, since we can't put the stored procedure on this server, I was going to store the code for the stored procedure into a variable by executing a SQL statement, retrieving the text from our home database, then use the text stored in this variable as the SQL command for the source:

[image: New method]

This way, I can still remotely change the SSIS OLE DB Source object `WHERE` clause (as long as I don't change the `SELECT` portion).

I can't imagine that this is very common, so I wanted to get some opinions - is there a better way to do this?  I don't want to put all of the code for this SP into the OLE DB Source editor directly because we can't afford to redeploy in case of a `WHERE` clause update.

Comment: Perhaps a script data source that loads the relevant query from the home db?  Although I'm not sure that's actually better.  Maybe we should ask idkfa.

Comment: You get an upvote for your troubles... and your reference ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the part down that many folks don't do and that's using Variables to drive your package execution. You are further correct in that you can't exactly swap out your columns. To be pedantic, which I am, you *can* completely change out the query as long as the same metadata is presented.

So, then this question becomes how best to accomplish allowing a package to have a query's filter driven by an external force. Factoring in maintainability, ease of debugging, etc.

My gut reaction is 3 Variables

- QueryBase: String. Hardcoded. `SELECT * FROM MyTable` except of course I'd enumerate my columns
- Query: String. EvaluateAsExpression = True Expression: @[User::QueryBase] + @[User::QueryFilter]
- QueryFilter: String

So, we use Query in the OLE DB Source much as you have your longer variable name in there. The only downside to this approach, pre SSIS-2012 is the limitation on string length in an expression. It was ... 4k I believe. If you assign a value of 5k characters, it's fine. It's just in the expression language, adding two strings together can't exceed 4k.

I didn't specify what QueryFilter is going to have in it or the magic to get it there. That, I would base on the bigger picture of your environment, usage, etc. but the general concept is that it will eventually turn into `WHERE Condition1 IS NOT NULL` but maybe in a full reload situation, it becomes an empty string.

So, what are our options for changing the value of QueryFilter

1. [/SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) is an optional parameter passed to the invoking process (dtexec.exe) that makes SSIS packages go. If you have a very limited set of choices and aren't interested in building additional infrastructure out to support the parameters, just hard code some examples. Approximately `dtexec /file p1.dtsx /set \Package.Variables[User::QueryFilter].Properties[Value];" WHERE Condition1 IS NOT NULL"` Save it into .bat files, different sql agent jobs, whatever. Click and run and you're done.
2. Configuration approach. SSIS offers native ability to use configurations from a SQL Server table, XML, Registry, Parent Package and Environment Variable for 2005 to current edition. The only downside to this approach is that it would not support concurrent execution with different parameters like the first would.
3. Environment approach. 2012 and 2014, with their new Project Deployment Model, give us the concept of Environments within the SSISDB catalog which is similar to configuration with a SQL Server table but it is done after development is complete and the packages are deployed. It's rather nice as it builds out a history of values used so if someone asks why is the data all wrong, you can write a query to pull back the parameters used and Oh look someone used the initial load filter instead of the daily. Whoopsidaisy. Same concern over concurrent execution and changing values.
4. Table driven approach. Instead of using the Configuration with SQL Server table backing, you roll your own table and then add into your package an Execute SQL Task to retrieve the filter, Single Row, into our QueryFilter Variable.
5. Script Task. Use whatever floats your boat to determine what the filter should be.
6. Message Queue. They have built in a [Message Queue Task](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/03/biml-message-queue-task.html) and might be of use here if you're already doing it. Otherwise, too much effort to manage

Comment: Thanks billinkc, I was originally planning on using option 4 as you described.  We are 2008 R2, so I am limited for option 3 (as nice as it sounds).